# Bootstrap input boxes are not spanning past 4 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine and the input boxes span 2, 3, and 4 columns.  However, If I change the column widths to :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

The column widths are not behaving as expected.  The col-lg-6 input box is not expanding 6 columns and nothing seems to be expanding past 4 columns.  Is something prohibiting the column from being expanded past a width of 4 by default?  Not sure what could be going on here.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using? The code you posted works fine in a bootply with 3.3: http://www.bootply.com/lAd1BHBGo3

Comment: I'm using version 3.0. Generated an MVC project from visual studio.

Comment: I'm still seeing it work with 3.0. (http://www.bootply.com/Rf0sCaHsnV) Perhaps there is some other CSS being applied to those elements. Unfortunately, since the problem is not present here, it is hard to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out what is going on.  The default MVC project template creates a _ViewStart.cshtml that references a _Layout.cshtml. In order to avoid the default layout created from ViewStart I added:

```
@{

Layout = null;
```

}